# Codigniter like query with or instead of and

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

below is my CI controller code to add multiple like in a query:

```
           $this->load->library('pagination');
            $currPage = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : "" ;
            $config['per_page'] = 7;
            if($currPage<2)
                    $currPage = "";   

            //search
            $prjSearch = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : "" ;
            if($prjSearch != "") {
                $this->db->like('projectName', $prjSearch, 'after');
                $this->db->like('projectName', $prjSearch, 'after');
                $this->db->like('projectName', $prjSearch, 'after');
            }
            $config['base_url'] = $this->config->site_url()."project/index/".$prjSearch."/"; 

            $this->db->select("project.*");     
            $query = $this->db->get('project',$config['per_page'],$currPage);
            $data['data'] = $query->result();
            echo $this->db->last_query();
            $config['cur_page'] = $data['cur_page'] = $currPage;
            $config['uri_segment'] = 4;
            //total count
            if($prjSearch != "") 
                $this->db->like('projectName', $prjSearch, 'after');            
            $query = $this->db->get('project');
            $config['total_rows'] = $query->num_rows();

            $this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

It generate below result:

```
SELECT `project`.* FROM (`project`) WHERE `projectName` LIKE 'kesh%' AND `projectName` LIKE 'kesh%' AND `projectName` LIKE 'kesh%' LIMIT 7
```

instead of "AND" between like i need to have "OR".

I dont want to use `$this->db->query();` as pagination will become complex or not supported by CI
Any help appreciated.

Comment: all 3 lines r same in like??

Comment: change **$this->db->like()** to **$this->db->or_like()**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this

```
$this->db->or_like();
```

for eg:

```
$this->db->like('title', 'match');
$this->db->or_like('body', $match);
```

So in you case,

```
$this->db->like('projectName', $prjSearch, 'after');
$this->db->or_like('projectName', $prjSearch, 'after');
$this->db->or_like('projectName', $prjSearch, 'after');
```

Answer (score 1):

use `$this->db->or_like` to get that. So change the like part from

```
$this->db->like('projectName', $prjSearch, 'after');
$this->db->like('projectName', $prjSearch, 'after');
$this->db->like('projectName', $prjSearch, 'after');
```

to this

```
$this->db->or_like('projectName', $prjSearch, 'after');
$this->db->or_like('projectName', $prjSearch, 'after');
$this->db->or_like('projectName', $prjSearch, 'after');
```